# Model User -> FriendRequests with Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have read many threads about mapping `User` and `Friends` but I have not been able to find a good answer. What I want is that an `ApplicationUser` should be able to have zero to many friend requests and later zero to many friends.

As you can see in the model `FriendRequest` has two `ApplicationUsers`, both `User` and `FutureFriend` and this is what's causing problems.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole,CustomUserClaim>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
    }

    [Required]
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FriendRequest> FriendRequests { get; set; }
}

public class FriendRequest
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int FutureFriendId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser FutureFriend { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RequestTime { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.FriendRequests)
    .WithRequired(f => f.User)
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
    .HasKey(f => new { f.UserId, f.FutureFriendId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
    .HasRequired(f => f.FutureFriend)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.FutureFriendId);

    //Did not work either
    //modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>().HasKey(f => new { UserId = f.UserId, FutureFriendId = f.FutureFriendId });
    //modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
    //  .HasRequired(f => f.User)
    //  .WithMany()
    //  .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId);
    //modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
    //    .HasRequired(f => f.FutureFriend)
    //    .WithMany()
    //    .HasForeignKey(f => f.FutureFriendId)
    //    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Error when trying to create the database:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.FriendRequests_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId' on table
>   'FriendRequests' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
>   KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
>   errors.

**Update:**

Decided to remodel the class, final solution can be found here: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999351/c-sharp-model-user-friend-requests-and-friends-with-entity-framework-code-first/39032018#39032018)

Comment: Add `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` after one of the `.HasForeignKey(..)` calls.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you! This worked, added `.WillCascadeOnDelet‌​e(false)` on both `.HasForeignKey(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @IvanStoev!

One solution in my model is by disabling `.WillCascadeOnDelet‌​e(false)` on one or both of the `.HasForeignKey(..)`. Since CASCADE causes corresponding rows to be deleted from the referencing table if that row is deleted from the parent table... and I'm a little paranoid.

I decided to disable the CascadeDeleteConvention on both one to many relations and many to many releations instead.

My solution:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Possible solution:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.FriendRequests)
    .WithRequired(f => f.User)
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
    .HasKey(f => new { f.UserId, f.FutureFriendId });

modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
    .HasRequired(f => f.FutureFriend)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.FutureFriendId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```