# Updating 2 usermodel lists when 1 changes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have 3 models in my EntityFramework class 1 is a UserModel the 2nd is a FriendModel and the 3rd is a ChatModel, (Which I will get into later)

The UserModel contains a virtual list of FriendModel. (A friend list)

Now the Issue I am having is when I try to add a friend to the User's friend list
I need a way to update the other user for this new added friend without adding a new column in the database for each user and friend.

Most solutions I've saw created 3 lists 1 is sent requests the 2nd is received
and 1 for combining them, But this still doesn't help me because the other user 
friend list is still empty when I add a friend.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999351/c-sharp-model-user-friend-requests-and-friends-with-entity-framework-code-first)
2. Creating two columns in the database for each newly added friend. (That caused Issues of its own)
3. Creating two UserModels in the FriendModel 1 for the User who sent the friend request and 1 for the The User who accepted the friend request.

And much more...

So far all of them caused issues of their own which made me give up and seek an answer here.

*UserModel code*

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The ID of the user
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; private set; }


    public string Username { get; internal set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The user's password
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] Password { get; internal set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The ip address of the client
    /// </summary>
    public string IPAddress { get; internal set; }



    /// <summary>
    /// The status of the client that other users see
    /// </summary>
    public UserStatus PublicStatus { get; internal set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A flag indicating if this user is offline or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsOnline { get; internal set; }



    /// <summary>
    /// The list of friends that the user is friends with
    /// </summary>
    public virtual List<FriendModel> FriendList { get; internal set; } = new List<FriendModel>();
```

*FriendModel code*

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A unique key for this friendship
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; private set; }



    // public int FriendID { get; internal set; }

    // public string FriendName { get; internal set; }


    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserModel))]
    public int UserModelID { get; internal set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserModel2))]
    public int UserModelID2 { get; internal set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// The status of the current request
    /// </summary>
    public FriendRequestStatus RequestStatus { get; internal set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// The messages that are associated with this friend
    /// </summary>
    public virtual List<ChatModel> MessageList { get; internal set; } = new List<ChatModel>();


    /// <summary>
    /// The user who requested this friendship
    /// </summary>
    public UserModel UserModel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The user who accpeted this friendship
    /// </summary>
    public UserModel UserModel2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: I would consider "friendship" a 1-1 relation, not a 1-many relation. You can still generate a collection (friend list) based on every friendship that this particular user participates in. But that requires bigger changes to your data model. What's most important to you: data integrity and efficiency, or maximizing performance when retrieving the data after it has been stored? The correct answer for your case depends on that prioritization.

Comment: To be honest I want to make sure it work first and then I can handle the optimization. But what do you mean by 1 to 1 relationship I need a list of friends not a single friend for every user, or am I getting two things mixed ? perhaps can you answer and show me what you mean, it will make things more clear to me

Comment: When you say "friend list", you're thinking of a list of users. But I'm suggesting to make this a two-step process by somewhat reframing your definitions to make the needed implementation clearer. Don't store a "friend" in the db, store a **"friendship"**. You can then generate a friend list by taking all the friendships in which [current user] participates, and for each friendship, select the other user (not the current user). I currently don't have the time to write a full answer as this will entail changing the entire data model.

Comment: The main point here is that 1-many relationships generally imply a hierarchical relationship. Friendship, by semantical definition, is a relationship of **equals**. It doesn't make sense to have a 1-many. Sure, bob and tom could both be your friends. But bob can have other friends too, no? Also, a user without friends should be allow to exist, no? You need to separate your understanding of what constitutes a _user_ and what a _friendship_ is (since it's inherently mutual).

Comment: I really can't understand what you mean. If I have a 1 to 1 relationship with a Friend that means I can only have 1 single friend for every user or am I missing something ? plus of course Bob can have different friends that's how it work right now but if I add "Bob" to my friend list "Bob" can't see me in his that's the main problem that I am facing